# Eclipse plugin that allows customized view of variables/objects while debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

While using C++ I have to deal with programs that have objects like matrices, linked lists etc

The default view of eclipse for variables while debugging is not very useful. It normally shows pointer values with value of only the first element in the array.

Below is how it is in eclipse:
[image: eclipse default variable view popup]

As we can see the matrix object has rows and columns integers and a double 2D array. I cannot see the values of the array in user friendly manner.

My question is that, is there anyway in eclipse (using plugin etc) through which I can define custom user interfaces (popups) for each object/class of my interest.

For example I would like to have the following (Matlab's view) kind of popup when I hover over an initialized matrix object:
[image: Matlab pop up for viewing matrix object]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JDT has a feature called [detail formatters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug_FAQ#What_are_detail_formatters.3F) to make that possible. The corresponding implementation for the CDT seems to have stalled after a [first prototype](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=237960) however, and did not make it into Eclipse.